# How do i create CollapsingToolbarLayout like feature in Nativescript Angular?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating an app which has the feature of  CollapsingToolbarLayout as available  in core android. I am unable to get that feature in Nativescript Agular core.How can i achieve this? I tried using GridLayout ,StackLayout and ScrollView but didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The actual native component is not implemented yet, but you can build a similar cross platform solution with layouts and animations, [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-make-a-collapsible-custom-actionbar-in-nativescript) is a blog that might help you.